# Bootstrap Carousel disappears

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

The Bootstrap carousel dissapears after the second slide and then reappears afterwards.  Does it need a container? Or are the libraries conflicting?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://www.sagu.edu/templates/sagu-redux/img/showcase-3.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Example headline.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.sagu.edu/templates/sagu-redux/img/showcase-2.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://www.sagu.edu/templates/sagu-redux/img/showcase-5.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
          <p class="lead">Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
          <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">‹</a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">›</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I think its somehow misinterpreting the active class as well?  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see in my answer, the part that suggests to change your syntax to match the documentation for this... try class="active item" instead of what you have (item active).

Comment: Sorry for misleading on the class syntax for the first img, from v3 docs it should be class="item active" (which you originally had). My bad!

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I have made the adjustment in switching the active position.  Still disappearing on every other slide.

Comment: Don't see the link on where to take a look at this issue anymore...

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `<div class="container">` and corresponding end `</div>` from each of your item's, including from the item active. This extra syntax is not needed. See the example syntax provided from [Twitter Bootstrap Documentation -v3](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel):

```
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

If you are still seeing issues, try refactoring your syntax to match the documentation. For example, it includes a carosel-indicators ol div to define the images in the carousel.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/khilley/r7wLmqc9/) showing your carousel working correctly. From the fiddle, I'm also calling transition.js and note that the version of carousel.js is 3.2 (not 2.3.2 which it appears you may be using). Also worth checking that you're using the latest bootstrap.min.css file. For the fiddle, I'm using jQuery 1.11.0, bootstrap.min.css, transition.js and carousel.js from [Twitter Bootstrap CDN](http://cdnjs.com/libraries/twitter-bootstrap). You can see from this fiddle how to make the right and left arrows look more like what you were describing you wanted.

Comment: Any idea why the arrows might be small?

Comment: Currently you have the arrows as text characters, and their styling comes from .carousel-control in your bootstrap.css (or bootstrap.min.css) file. There, the font-size value reads 20px. If you bump that up to 60px or 80px, should be more to your liking. Did the rest of my answer help?

Comment: I was able to find it.  Thanks for your help!  Now to get it work without disappearing when it becomes active.

Comment: Are you testing changes locally? Your live site still shows the extra div containers I suggest removing, along with the possibly incorrect class for active item. I'm going to modify my answer slightly next, looks like some formatting glitches there.

Comment: I was just making the adjustments.  Currently, it's on a cms, so changes are reflected immediately.  What extra div containers are  you referring to?

Comment: Cool. Within each of your divs (for each image in the carousel) it looks like you've got an extra <div class="container"> and corresponding </div>. From the syntax example in my Answer, that is not needed. Make sense now?

Comment: okay, I too the container tags off, but still running into some weird problems.

Comment: It might have something to do with what it does in between the active.

Comment: Just so you're totally inline with the documented example, try adding in the <ol class="carousel-indicators"> code (from my answer). This will go directly before your <!-- Carousel items -->.

Comment: Okay, I added the <ol> tags back.

Comment: @khilley Don't consult Bootstrap v2's documentation when Saguweb's site is using Bootstrap v3!

Comment: Sorry I didn't see carousel docs on 3 when I looked earlier. I'll update my answer but don't know if that solves this issue. Suggestions to remove the extra divs and include carousel indicators are still valid.

Comment: I got it to initially work but then when I load the joomla files, it goes into the same error.  I don't have control over what joomla loads but there are some jquery no conflict, jquery-migrate, and a jquery.min.  Do you have any recommendation as far as maybe switching the slideshow or what slideshow module would place nice with these parameters?

Comment: Just took a look at your demo, and the carousel is no longer disappearing. It looks like you've got joomla files being called too. Are you good to go with this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you forgot the `data-ride="carousel"` in the very first div. I don't know if that will help, but it's worth a shot. [Bootstrap's example for reference.](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel)

Comment: `data-ride` makes the Carousel automatically start cycling on page load.